# Dart Provider: not available at the immediate child

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, bloc

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
        create: (context) {
          return HomeBloc(homeRepo: HomeRepository());
        },
        child: BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context).state is HomeStateLoading
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Container());
  }
```

I am confused with the error:

```
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type HomeBloc.
No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to
BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>().
```

Didn't I just create the `HomeBloc` at its immediate parent? What does it want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `context` passed into the `build` method of your widget class to look for a parent `BlocProvider`. However, that context is the widget tree as far as your widget class sees it. Because of this, your `BlocProvider.of` is looking for a `BlocProvider` that is a parent of your *widget class*. If you want to get the provider that is the immediate parent, you need a new `context` object in which the `BlocProvider` is an ancestor in the widget tree. The easiest way to do this is with a `Builder` widget:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
    create: (context) {
      return HomeBloc(homeRepo: HomeRepository());
    },
    child: Builder(
      builder: (newContext) => BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(newContext).state is HomeStateLoading
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : Container(),
    ),
  );
}
```

That being said, it's pretty redundant to create a provider and then immediately reverence the provider. Providers are for retrieving stuff further down the widget tree, not typically for immediate descendants. In this case, using a provider is overkill and there isn't really any reason to not just have the bloc be a field of your class and reference it directly.

Comment: Thank you man. But I still cannot fully agree with what Provider does / defines. Apparently the `BlocProvider.of()` is called within the `child: `. How the heck come it is not within its widget tree? Is she lying to me this is my child???

Comment: @nigong It has nothing to do with where `BlocProvider.of()` is called and everything to do with the context object you are passing to it. You are passing `context` which comes from the parent widget class (let's call it `Foo`). There is no `BlocProvider` that is an ancestor of `Foo`, so as far as `context` is concerned, `BlocProvider` doesn't exist. That's why you need `Builder` to get a _new_ context object `newContext` that _does_ have a `BlocProvider` as an ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value) :

> The easiest way to read a value is by using the static method
>   Provider.of(BuildContext context).
>
> This method will look up in the widget tree starting from the widget
>   associated with the BuildContext passed and it will return the nearest
>   variable of type T found (or throw if nothing is found).

In your case it starts looking up the widget tree from your whole widget (associated to the `BuildContext`).

So you need to move your `BlocProvider` to be an ancestor of this widget.

If for some reason this is not possible, you can use `Consumer`, which allows obtaining a value from a provider when you don't have a `BuildContext` that is a descendant of the said provider.

Read https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html