# Provider not found in anchestor

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Here I am with another provider problem.
I have a main widget that switch the main view, this widget is called switcher.dart

I initialize the provider inside a multiprovider into th switcher and i use it in a view loaded (mainPage.dart). The view gave me the error Provider not found.

switcher.dart

```
 import '../providers/mainPageProvider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/userProvider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import '../widgets/login.dart';
import '../widgets/mainPage.dart';
import '../widgets/splash.dart';

class Switcher extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<UserProvider, MainPageProvider>(
          create: (context) => MainPageProvider.init(
              Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false)),
          update: (context, userProvider, mainPageProvider) =>
              mainPageProvider..update(userProvider),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<UserProvider>(
        builder: (context, user, _) {
          print('switcher notifyed');
          print(user.status);
          switch (user.status) {
            case UserStatus.Uninitialized:
              return Splash();
              break;
            case UserStatus.Authenticated:
              return MainPage();
              break;
            case UserStatus.Unauthenticated:
              return Login();
              break;
            case UserStatus.Authenticating:
              return Login();
              break;
            case UserStatus.Checking:
              return Splash();
              break;
            default:
              return Splash();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

into the mainPage view i use a simple consumer of MainPageProvider but says:

```
The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown building Consumer<MainPageProvider>(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MainPageProvider> above this Consumer<MainPageProvider> Widget

To fix, please:

  * Ensure the Provider<MainPageProvider> is an ancestor to this Consumer<MainPageProvider> Widget
  * Provide types to Provider<MainPageProvider>
  * Provide types to Consumer<MainPageProvider>
  * Provide types to Provider.of<MainPageProvider>()
  * Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
  * Ensure the correct `context` is being used
```

view Example of consumer in this case mainPage.dart

```
import 'package:client/providers/mainPageProvider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../widgets/smallCard.dart';
import 'contoCard.dart';

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child:  Container(
                        height: 100,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: Consumer<MainPageProvider>(
                          builder: (context, mainPageProvider, _) {
                            if(mainPageProvider.conti == null){
                                  return SpinKitPulse(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  );
                            }else if(mainPageProvider.conti.length ==0){
                          return Text(
                        'Ancora nessun conto',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "sofiapro", fontSize: 14),
                      );
                            }else{
                              return ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemCount: mainPageProvider.conti.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                      var conti = mainPageProvider.conti;
                                      var conto = conti[index];
                                      return ContoCard(conto);
                                    },
                                  );
                            }

                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    .......
```

The switcher it seems an anchestor to me, because the view is loaded as a child, i tried to change the import way from import '../providers/mainPageProvider.dart';   to  import 'package:client/providers/mainPageProvider.dart'; but the error was still there.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It seems to be an ancestor but it is not. Either use `Consumer` or move your `ChangeNotifier` to an ancestor context. See my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724655/1274485

Comment: The snippet you gave is invalid. The error is caused by a `Consumer< MainPageProvider>` but your snippet does not include one

Comment: @Yann39 I use a consumer inside my view. My goal is to have my providers to be accessible from all my views(like is my  UserMainProvider  in the main.dart). If i move the change notifier inside my view (in this case mainPage view) it works, because i already tried it, but the provider is not accessible by other views because is no more an anchestor.

Comment: @RémiRousselet sorry i don't understand, which snippet is invalid? My switcher.dart contains the provider into the create function

Comment: Yes but you are not showing the widget that is trying to read the provider. It is not the `Consumer` shown here, but another one.

Comment: Ah ok sorry about that, i know is another one, but is a simple consumer. I update immediatly the code of the question

Comment: I have added the code of the view